# Have I discovered a jQuery UI bug?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I have an element with a `:hover` state that I call `$.draggable()` on. The helper is a clone, so when I drag the element, a clone is created and that's dragged around instead. However, some of the  time, the `:hover` state on my draggable element isn't turned off and I have to execute a second mouseover/out without dragging before the element will return to its original state. It's all fairly standard stuff, here's the `$.draggable()` call:

```
$("#" + slot).draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    appendTo: "body",
    scope: "my_scope",
    start: function (event, ui) {
        // do some stuff when the element starts being dragged
    },
    stop: function () {
        // do some stuff when the element stops being dragged
    }
});
```

And here are all the CSS styles the element has:

```
.inventory_item {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #222;
    font-family: Courier;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 10px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: x-large;
    opacity: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #111;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #111;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #111;
}
```

And its `:hover` state:

```
.inventory_item:hover {
     -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #555;
     -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #555;
     box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #555;
}
```

Now, as far as I know, there's no way to change the `:hover` state of an element with Javascript. My other option, then, is to use classes and Javascript mouseover/out events to simulate a controllable `:hover` state. But before I do that, are there any known fixes for this? Is this a common jQuery UI bug? My searches haven't turned up anything.

Here's a screenshot of the problem:

[image: Image of the issue]

You can't see the mouse cursor there because of my screenshot software, but it's just over the element that's being dragged out. Even though it's not over the draggable element, which is highlighted, said element's `:hover` state is on. Not cool.

Comment: Interesting, may we have a small fiddle ?

Comment: when you start dragging, change the classname of the element, so that it is no longer eligible for the hover state.

Comment: @soyuka: I'll try to reproduce it. No promises, though.

Comment: @TravisJ: Which element? The helper or the original element?

Comment: @ElliotBonneville - The helper (which is the one you don't want to have hover I thought)

Comment: No, the issue is the original element having the hover. The helper is the one with the `|` in it.

Comment: @soyuka: Interesting, can't reproduce the issue in jsFiddle.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville Hmm try your css hover state effect with javascript (on mouseenter / mouseleave)

Comment: Yes, that'll be my next step. I'll get back to you when I finish.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville Did anything ever come out of this?

Comment: @AustinBurk I don't remember now. I think I moved to a different solution. Sorry.